# SQL Database singleton for storing db version information

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, singleton

I need a very simple thing in SQL Database - I am using SQL Server and/or SQL Compact.
In c# I would write it like this

```
public class MyApp
{
   public static int Version = 1;
}
```

e.g. I need to store configuration information in a form of singleton in SQL database.
Is there any better method than to create table with only one record? 
Actually for my present needs  it would be sufficient to have only one version number stored with database, but it must work both for SQL Server and SQL Compact database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A table with one row is probably your best approach. Normally, you'd use a CHECK() constraint to guarantee you'll have only one row.

```
create table your_table_name (
  one_row integer not null unique
    default 1 check (one_row = 1),
  version varchar(5) not null unique
);

insert into your_table_name values (1, '0.0.0');
```

If your platform doesn't support CHECK() constraints, but does support GRANT and REVOKE, you might be able to insert one row into the version table, then grant *only* update permissions. (Revoke delete and insert permissions.)

If your platform doesn't support CHECK() constraints, and doesn't support GRANT and REVOKE, but *does* support foreign key references, you might be able to replace the CHECK() constraint above with a foreign key reference to single-row table. This doesn't entirely solve the problem--you still have a single-row table that you can't adequately constrain.

If your dbms supports regular expressions in CHECK() constraints, you *could* add additional constraints to guarantee your version number follows a regular expression. You could also split the "version" into several columns of integers, each with its own constraints. But varchar(5) and varchar(7) seem to be the most common.

Comment: Unfortunately CHECK constraints are not supported in any version of SQL Compact.

Comment: @VDohnal: Thanks. I expanded my answer to consider those limitations.